# Android service binding

Tags: android

I have Problem understanding the Binding to a service 
I've created a simple song player, with a service to play the song.
I've created a log to track the binding and unbinding.
the problem is when i exit the app Unbinding log appears but when i go back to the app there is no binding log message ,i'm able to control play and pause of the song though

```
public class PlayService extends Service {

MediaPlayer mPlayer;
public IBinder mBinder=new LocalBinder();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("TAG","Create");
    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.askme);
}


//since we want the song to be played in the background then we need to start the service


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("TAG","Start");
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            stopSelf();
        }
    });

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("TAG","Bind");
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("TAG","Unbind");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("TAG","ReBind");

    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("TAG","Destroy");
    mPlayer.release();

    super.onDestroy();
}
//here are the play and pause methods frm the user

public void playSong(){
    mPlayer.start();
}
public void pauseSong(){
    mPlayer.pause();
}

public boolean isPlaying(){
   return mPlayer.isPlaying();
}





//since Binder already Extends IBinder  so
//we can create LocalBinder Class which extends IBinder Interface

public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
    //this method for returning an instance of our service in the MainActivity
    public  PlayService getService(){
        return PlayService.this;
    }

}
```

}

and main Activity as following

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG ="TAG" ;
public PlayService mPlayService;
private Button mDownloadButton;
private Button mSongButton;
private boolean mBound=false;
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection=new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        //the iBinder object is the returned value from onBind() method in our service
        mBound=true;
        //we need to get an instance of our service PlayerService so we can play or Pause the song
        PlayService.LocalBinder binder = (PlayService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
        //and here finally we are getting an instance of our service
        mPlayService= binder.getService();


        if (mPlayService.isPlaying()){
            mSongButton.setText("Pause");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBound=false;
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDownloadButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.download_button);
    mSongButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.song_button);


    mDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            for (String song:Playlist.songs){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartDownloadService.class);
                intent.putExtra(TAG,song);
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    mSongButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //here we can play or Pause the song
            //but first we need to know if we are already bound to the service
            if (mBound){
                if (mPlayService.isPlaying()){
                    mPlayService.pauseSong();
                    mSongButton.setText("Play");
                }else {
                    //but here we need the service to be started and keep playing in the background
                    //even if we unbound from the service when we exit the App
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                    mPlayService.playSong();
                    mSongButton.setText("Pause");
                }
            }

        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,PlayService.class);
    bindService(intent,mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound){
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mBound=false;
    }
}
```

}

if someone can explain

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your service twice in your code.
Once as a started service and then as a bind service. Remove the started service code and most probably it should work as intended.

Remove this from your code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayService.class);
                startService(intent);
                mPlayService.playSong();
                mSongButton.setText("Pause");
```

as you are binding service in **on Resume()** method.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,PlayService.class);
bindService(intent,mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: if i don't start the service the song will stop if i exit the app

Comment: instead of your startService intent in else part call the bind service code in else block too.

Answer (score 0):

You should **start** and **bind** your music service like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart invoked !");
        // Start/Bind to play back service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, PlayService.class);
        if (isMyServiceRunning(PlayService.class)
                && mBound== false) {
            this.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            this.startService(serviceIntent);
            this.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Log.i(TAG, "Media Player service is created new -------------------");
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop invoked !");
        if(mBound) {
            Log.i(TAG, "unbinding service !");
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mBound= false;
        }
    }
```

To Check service is running or not:

```
 /**
     * Utility function to check if a service is running.
     */
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

I found the Reason

the system calls your service's onBind() method to retrieve the IBinder only when the first client binds. The system then delivers the same IBinder to any additional clients that bind, without calling onBind() again.
that's why i'm not getting the Log message from onBind() and onUnbind() method, but I've used a log message in onServiceConnected() and i got it when i ran the App again.